# How to get all metadata of the contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, pages

[image]

[image]

Site contents images are attached to this question page.

I need to crawl the metadata for the `pages/atozindex`.

It contains the a to z documents. How to form the request by using restAPI?
Can anyone assist on this?

```
https://www.sitecontent.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your URL, you specify the title of the list as `'Pages'`. It should be `'Site Pages'`. It generally shows up on the Quick Launch nav as `'Pages'`, but that's not actually the title of the list. Other than that, your end point URL is correct, so this works:

```
$.ajax({
    // same REST end point, but changed the list title
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
    },
    complete: function(request) {
        console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    }, 
    error: function(request) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    }
});
```

The response looks like this:

```
Request: {
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"value\":[{\"Id\":4,\"Title\":null,\"ID\":4,\"FileRef\":\"/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/Sub\"},{\"Id\":1,\"Title\":null,\"ID\":1,\"FileRef\":\"/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/Home.aspx\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":null,\"ID\":2,\"FileRef\":\"/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/How To Use This Library.aspx\"},{\"Id\":3,\"Title\":null,\"ID\":3,\"FileRef\":\"/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/slider.aspx\"},{\"Id\":5,\"Title\":null,\"ID\":5,\"FileRef\":\"/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/Sub/Tester.aspx\"}]}",
    "responseJSON": {
        "value": [
            {
                "Id": 4,
                "Title": null,
                "ID": 4,
                "FileRef": "/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/Sub"
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Title": null,
                "ID": 1,
                "FileRef": "/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/Home.aspx"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": null,
                "ID": 2,
                "FileRef": "/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/How To Use This Library.aspx"
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Title": null,
                "ID": 3,
                "FileRef": "/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/slider.aspx"
            },
            {
                "Id": 5,
                "Title": null,
                "ID": 5,
                "FileRef": "/sites/csrdemos/SitePages/Sub/Tester.aspx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
}
```

As you can see, this returns the meta data for all pages in the 'Site Pages' library, even if they are in sub-folders.  To get additional fields back, just add them to the `$select=` query parameter.  It is a comma separated list of field internal names.

I tested this in the browser console on a SharePoint online site where jQuery is loaded into each page. If you don't have jQuery loaded on your site, you can test it by first running this in the console:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@1.12.4/dist/jquery.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

This will load jQuery. If you refresh the page, you'll need to load jQuery again. Then you can copy and paste the above code as is, and it will console.log the returned results.

Comment: I tried to as your query in POSTMAN but i'm getting the below error. Still getting the confusion for  formation of Request


https://www.sitecontent.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages/atozindex.aspx')/items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,async: false,



https://www.sitecontent.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('atozindex.aspx')/items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,async: false,




"value": "The expression \"ID,Title,FileRef,async: false,\" is not valid."

Comment: I am using POSTMan Request with Java. Could u please assist on the same. I tried site pages but even though the same error.

Comment: The URL in your comment, doesn't look like my URL. First, you're trying to run `GetByTitle('Pages/atozindex.aspx')`, which isn't even close to `GetByTitle('Site Pages')` in my answer. You also added `,async` to the end of your query, so now SharePoint is looking for a field named `async`, which is not valid.  I did end up with some extra spaces in my URL, so I've edited my answer to remove them and also provided some additional information about how I tested my code in the browser debug tools. I don't have Postman, so I can't advise you on testing with that tool.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, the title is case sensitive, so `'site pages'` will not work, it needs to be `'Site Pages'`.

Comment: `site pages` will not work, needs to be `Site Pages`, and remove `,async` from the end of your query.

Comment: No Joe. Actually showing the site pages. but i need to capture the data of https://kmwin.ifc.org/sites/pnp/Pages/atozindex.aspx  -------------------------- it contains the list of documents, i need to crawl the same meta data for a to z entire documents data. Which is mentioned in first images for policy and procedure. also highlighted the a to z i need to capture.

Comment: Sorry, but your question said pages, and your query was getting all pages, so I assumed that's what you wanted and atozindex.aspx was just an example of one of the pages. So am I to understand that you only want the meta data for that one page? I can update my answer for that, it will be a different REST end point, let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: Joe McShea Can u please assist this issue.Actually i need to  capture the metadata like document title, code, type, year these details including for all the lists like adminstration, b for backup, etc. it would have been highlighted in first images as A B C D E F G H like it contains all documents. so i need to capture those entire data

Comment: How to form the Request for capturing the metadata for all. Thanks

Comment: The query above will return the meta data for ALL pages in the 'Site Pages' library. If you want ALL pages in any library, you need to update your question, because that's not clear from your question?  And if so, is it all pages in any library, or including all documents, or including even list items?  And is it throughout the site, or throughout the entire site collection?  In general, there is no end point that will get you all items throughout the site or site collection, other than search.

Comment: Actually need to capture the data for all the values of like as A B C D E F g H upto z it contains around 250 documents so i need to capture for all those title, code, year and type. formation of request is needed for POSTMAN